# Is there a way to make a multi-dimensional array object side-by-side with certain rules?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, multidimensional-array

In the loop of the map function, I want to get the top and left values of the CSS position and output another value in the array as per the position in the Vue.js for statement, but I can't get the top value as expected.

**Expected results**

I want to align the CSS top.

[expected result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCiBH.png)

**Current status**

[current status img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w87V6.png)

because the top is generated each time it is looped.

In order to create top and left, we loop through the array object using the map function. I would like to get the value of top each time I loop, but since it is currently a constant value, how can I get the value of top for each task_code?

Here is the code.

```js
// data.js

export default
[
    [ // user_id:1 start
        [
            {
                input_time: 8,
                user_id: 1,
                task_code: "100",
                daily_day: "2021-02-01"
            },
            {
                input_time: 8,
                user_id: 1,
                task_code: "100",
                daily_day: "2021-02-02"
            },
            {
                input_time: 8,
                user_id: 1,
                task_code: "100",
                daily_day: "2021-02-08"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                input_time: 8,
                user_id: 1,
                task_code: "101",
                daily_day: "2021-02-03"
            }
        ]
    ],// user_id:1 end
    [ // user_id:2 start
        [
            {
                input_time: 5,
                user_id: 2,
                task_code: "105",
                daily_day: "2021-02-01"
            },
            {
                input_time: 8.5,
                user_id: 2,
                task_code: "105",
                daily_day: "2021-02-02"
            },
        ],
        [
            {
                input_time: 0.5,
                user_id: 2,
                task_code: "100",
                daily_day: "2021-02-01"
            },
            {
                input_time: 3.5,
                user_id: 2,
                task_code: "100",
                daily_day: "2021-02-04"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                input_time: 1,
                user_id: 2,
                task_code: "103",
                daily_day: "2021-02-01"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

```js
Vue.js

<template>
  <div>
      <div class="p_hello">
          <div v-for="(d, index) in fn" :key="`first-${index}`" class="first">
              <div v-for="(i, index) in d" :key="`second-${index}`" class="second">
                  <div v-for="(j, index) in i" :key="`third-${index}`">
                      <div class="third" :style="j.style" :class="inputColor(j.item.input_time)">
                          {{j.item.input_time}}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'
import data from '../assets/api/data'
// console.log('data', data)

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            data,
            date: '2021-02-01',
            size: 30
        }
    },
    computed : {
        fn () {
            const start = moment(this.date)
            let top = 20
            let style
            return this.data.map(value => {
                return value.map(value => {
                    return value.map(item => {
                        const from = moment(item.daily_day)
                        let diff = from.diff(start, 'days')
                        let left = diff * this.size
                        style = {
                            top: `${top}px`,
                            left: `${left}px`,
                            color: 'black'
                        }
                        top = top + 40

                        return {
                            style,
                            item
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        inputColor(input) {
            if (input > 7) {
                return 'green'
            }
            if (input < 4) {
                return 'red'
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>


<style>
    .first {
        position: relative;
        display:flex;
    }
     .second {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;

        background-color:azure;

    }

    .third {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .green {
        background: rgb(153, 235, 210);
    }
    .red {
        background: rgb(236, 81, 127);
    }
</style>
```

[coding picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w4fY.png)